# Gilman Reagent with vinyl chloride

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, polymers, halides

What are the products formed when vinyl chloride reacts with dimethyl copper?

I thought the product formed would be propene. But answer given is PolyVinylChloride. How does polymerization take place?

Comment: I thought Gilman Reagent is lithium dialkyl copper. I would expect propene to be formed too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anionic_addition_polymerization

Comment: @orthocresol so the reaction will start with a nucleophilic attack by a methyl carbanion on vinyl chloride. Will this nucleophile attck the anti-bonding pi orbital?

Comment: Yes. You can't make propene - that would involve a SN2 (which organometallics are notoriously bad at) at a sp2 centre (which is extremely rare to begin with)